# Does Godel's incompleteness theorem only apply to formal axiomatic systems?

Tags: logic

We call G the formula that in the formal axiomatic system employed by Godel to formalise arithmetic has the meaning of:

"I am not provable in this system".

We know that this formula G is true in that axiomatic system since we can exclude that it is false. But why can we say that it is also true in arithmetic itself?
After all, within arithmetic such a formula is only a set of symbols, and even if well formed it can still be a false formula.
How can we say that such a formula is also true within arithmetic and not only in the aforementioned formal system that formalises arithmetic?
We come to this conclusion because the formula G also within mathematics retains the meaning of:

"I am not provable in this system"

or are there other reasons for considering it true within arithmetic?

Comment: There’s no such thing as “true in an axiomatic system”, only provable, refutable, or undecidable. If the sentence is indeed not provable in the system, like it says, that means the sentence is true “in arithmetic itself”.

Comment: YES............

Answer (score 1):

"Does Godel's incompleteness theorem only apply to formal axiomatic systems?" Yes -- assuming that by "formal" you mean something like "recursively axiomatised", and not "merely formal, uninterpreted, devoid of meaning" (Godel's incompleteness theorem applies to interpreted theories too!)

"But why can we say that $G$ is also true in arithmetic itself?" For ultimately just the same reason that we can say that e.g. "$s(0) + ss(0) = sss(0)$" as a sentence of formalised first-order Peano Arithmetic is "true in arithmetic". Formalised Peano Arithmetic is not an uninterpreted game of symbol-shuffling; its constituent expressions are assigned interpretations, and given those interpretations, $s(0) + ss(0) = sss(0)$" comes out as true if and only if 1 + 2 = 3. But it is true that 1 + 2 = 3. Hence "$s(0) + ss(0) = sss(0)$", on the standard interpretation built into the language of Peano Arithmetic, is true -- a truth of arithmetic, indeed.

It is the same with, say $G_{PA}$, a canonical Gödel sentence for (your favourite version of) formalised first-order Peano Arithmetic, built using (your favourite version of) a scheme for Gödel-numbering. This is so constructed that, on the standard interpretation built into the language of Peano Arithmetic, this complicated arithmetical sentence is true if and only if no number is the Gödel-number (on your numbering scheme) of a proof on $G_{PA}$ in formalised first-order Peano Arithmetic. And that is true, because you've proved $G_{PA}$ is unprovable. So $G_{PA}$, a sentence of formal arithmetic, is true on the standard interpretation built into the language of Peano Arithmetic  -- again, then, a truth of arithmetic, indeed.

For more clarity about this sort of thing, see one of the standard textbooks. Of for shorter read, there is my freely downloadable [*Gödel Without (Too Many) Tears*](https://www.logicmatters.net/igt/).